# get html form elements after submit

Tags: java, javascript, html

In a HTML form, After clicking submit button, html elements present 
  in the form can convert into html for example if form contains two elements

```
       Name : textbox value 10
       password: textbox value xx
       button  : submit
```

after i submit i want o/p as

```
<input type="text" value="10" />
<input type="text" value="xx" />
<input type="button" value="submit"/>
```

using java or js

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question?

Comment: Are you wanting to recreate the submitted data in an html format?

Comment: You mean: after the page reloads on submit, you want your form elements to be prefilled with the values you set, before the submit?

Comment: So you have two text elements, what exactly do you want to happen after you click submit? Maybe you need to re-read your questions before you post.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to comments, you need server side (for example PHP) for this.
The posted values have to be directed back to the page, like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']>" /><br />
    Password: <input type="text" name="pass" value="<?php echo $_POST['pass']>" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="submit" />
</form>
```